# Convert UNIX timestamp to str and str to UNIX timestamp in python

Tags: python

For example:

I want to convert UNIX timestamps `1385629728` to str `"2013-11-28 17:08:48"`,
and convert str `"2013-11-28 17:08:48"` to UNIX timestamps `1385629728`.

Comment: Please avoid asking straightforwardly google-able questions on SO. It decreases the standard of the average question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it as below:

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

import datetime, time

def ts2string(ts, fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"):
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
    return dt.strftime(fmt)

def string2ts(string, fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, fmt)
    t_tuple = dt.timetuple()
    return int(time.mktime(t_tuple))

def test():
    ts = 1385629728

    string = ts2string(ts)
    print string

    ts = string2ts(string)
    print ts

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use datetime.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1385629728")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
2013-11-28 14:38:48
>>> print int(datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-11-28 14:38:48', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime("%s"))
1385629728
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time 

# where epoch is your epoch time value 
time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", 
                        time.localtime(epoch))
```

[Source](http://blog.infoentropy.com/Convert_Epoch_time_Normal_time_with_Python)